# Wordpress/Woocommerce only show category to a single role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, role

Searched all day, can't seem to find an answer.  I've tried similar function snippets hoping to alter them since I'm not a coder, but none of them have worked.

I need to hide the "professional" category of products from all but the wholesale customer role.  Looking to add a filter to functions, not in a template.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please clarify your question editing it, because is really not clear, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.